# Communication between Android phone and Linux Gadget Serial

Tags: android, embedded-linux, cdc, usbserial

I have an Android phone running some custom app, trying to establish connection over serial with a custom board. The board has an ARM CPU running Yocto and is configured as an ACM CDC device using *Linux Gadget Serial*. The communication takes place over USB-C.

Testing everything separately works as expected. I used a custom ACM device (based on an STM32 MCU) to test the Android app and it both detects and communicates with it.

However, when I try to communicate with the Linux gadget device, it connects for a very brief moment and then drops the connection. I have tried the [Android Serial Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_usb_terminal&hl=en&gl=US) too, which uses the same [serial library](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/tree/master) as my code, and I get same results:

```
15:45:11:596 Connected to CDC device
15:45:11:932 Connection lost
```

Also tried setting different vendor and product id numbers on my gadget serial, but with no success.

Has anyone tried something similar?

**Edit:**
The usb-serial-for-android mentions a workaround regarding "Probing for Unrecognized Devices". Unfortunately, even though I fiddled a lot with that, nothing really came out.